# jQuery appendTo() <tr>

Tags: jquery, dom

I am attempting to move a table row from 1 table to another, appending to the last row in the table.

```
function transfer()
{
  $('#gallery_' + galleryID).fadeOut(function(){
      $(this).appendTo('#tbl_proofed tr:last').fadeIn();
  });
}
```

This is appending it within the last  tag, how do I go about appending after. May just have to use another method but was trying this because it copies all the element and its children.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simply replace `.append()` with [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after) and add `.next()` to target the moved row.

```
function transfer()
{
  $('#gallery_' + galleryID).fadeOut(function(){
      $(this).after('#tbl_proofed tr:last').next().fadeIn();
  });
}
```

Edit: i may have mis-interpreted your question. If you wanted the copy to go in the other direction, it would be: [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter)

```
function transfer()
{
  $('#gallery_' + galleryID).fadeOut(function(){
      $(this).insertAfter('#tbl_proofed tr:last').fadeIn();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  remove the `tr:last` and appendTo the table

```
function transfer()
{
  $('#gallery_' + galleryID).fadeOut(function(){
      $(this).appendTo('#tbl_proofed').fadeIn();
  });
}
```

Comment: if have a tfoot add `tbody` to selector

Answer (score 0):

Just use the .after() method like:

```
function transfer()
{
  $('#gallery_' + galleryID).fadeOut(function(){
      $(this).after('#tbl_proofed tr:last').fadeIn();
  });
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/after/